# Program error with MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my table creation query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma_usergroups` (
  `usergroup` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `tab` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `allowed` enum(‘Y’,’N’) NOT NULL DEFAULT ‘N’,
  PRIMARY KEY (`usergroup`,`tab`,`allowed`)
)
```

Then MySQL said error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
'â€˜Yâ€™,â€™Nâ€™) NOT NULL DEFAULT â€˜Nâ€™,PRIMARY KEY (`usergroup`,`tab`,`' at line 7
```

Can you explain what MySQL said?

Comment: use the english input for single quote

Answer (score 4):

The syntax error is due to the fact that you are not using plain single quotes.

Try replacing

```
enum(‘Y’,’N’) NOT NULL DEFAULT ‘N’
```

with

```
enum('Y','N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N'
```

(Note the use of `'` instead of `‘` and `’` ).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using typographical quotes (`‘`...`’`) rather than the ordinary ASCII single quote (`'`). Your query should look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma_usergroups` (
  `usergroup` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `tab` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `allowed` enum('Y','N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  PRIMARY KEY (`usergroup`,`tab`,`allowed`)
)
```

Some word processors, such as Microsoft Word, have the annoying habit of auto-"correcting" these even if you type in the correct characters. This is configurable of course, but at my $workplace, the settings tend to revert to their default values occasionally.

It is usually better to use a **text** editor to write code.

Answer (score -1):

put the code like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pma_usergroups (

usergroup varchar(64) NOT NULL,

tab varchar(64) NOT NULL,

allowed enum('Y','N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',

PRIMARY KEY (usergroup,tab,allowed)

)
```

Comment: Please explain why. Don't just dump a block of code.

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pma_usergroups (
  usergroup varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  tab varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  allowed enum('Y','N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',//Put N in single quote
  PRIMARY KEY (usergroup,tab,allowed)
)
```

[Working Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/66ef3)